# No encuentro el error sobre un ej de JS

Tags: javascript

Buenas podrían ayudarme a comprender!!

Escribí una función `sumatoriaHasta`, que tome como parámetro `X` (un valor numérico) y retorne (no imprima) la sumatoria de los números desde el 0 hasta el número X. Por ejemplo:

```js
sumatoriaHasta(4);  // Ejecuto la función con el valor 4 como parámetro
6  // Éste es el resultado de la operación.
```

Esta función haría la siguiente cuenta:  `0 + 1 + 2 + 3` (NO llegamos al 4, porque la función dice hasta X , no dice inclusive)

Mi **Código** creo ir bien?

```js
function sumatoriaHasta4(x) {
    var suma = 0 
    for (var i=0; i < x; i++) 
    return suma
}
```

Comment: si gracias, no había pegado el codigo.

Comment: Hola, recuerda pasar por el apartado de [ask] si eres nuevo :)

Comment: Claramente la sintaxis del `for` es errónea, debes hacer `for(let i=0; i<x; i++){suma+=i}` y con eso se soluciona todo

Comment: si, christian muchas gracias me faltaba eso sumar los valores de i  y terminar el for, de echo tenia un 4 en *sumatoriaHasta* que no iva xd --- gracias Saludos.